# How to push data into firebase without overriding

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want insert these notes in firebase realtime data.. how to generate the keys(Note1, Note2, Note3.....) and push the note along with it like the picture attached... i also tried generating random keys but it always overriding the data which i don't want..

[image: Snapshot of data]

```
String note = ETNote.getText().toString();
DatabaseReference noteRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(userID).child("Notes");
String noteID = noteRef.push().getKey();
Map newPost = new HashMap();
newPost.put(noteID, note);
noteRef.setValue(newPost);
Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "Note Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: This looks like a collection of notes. Firebase highly recommends against using sequentially, increasing indexes for this. See https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
DatabaseReference ref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Notes").push();
ref.child("note1").setValue(notes1);
ref.child("note2").setValue(notes2);
ref.child("note3").setValue(notes3);
```

then you will have:

```
Notes
  randomid
      note1: notes
      note2: notes
      note3: notes
```

Comment: sorry.. i think i was not clear.. i dont know how many notes i will have.. thats why i need to generate Note1, Note2, Note3.. and so on ... with program...  like when i push a note it will automatically create the child(Note1), next time Note2.. and so on

Comment: why do note1 and note2? just seperate the notes by the randomid, So you will have Notes/randomid/note:details/randomid/note:details.. Also you can add other details other than notes

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways.

The first is to address each child node directly, similar to what Peter shows in his answer:

```
noteRef.push().setValue(newPost);
```

The other is to create a map of (potentially multiple) new notes, and then update the `noteRef`:

```
String noteID = noteRef.push().getKey();
Map newPost = new HashMap();
newPost.put(noteID, note);
noteRef.updateChildren(newPost);
```